# How to Insert Block in AutoCAD using python

Tags: python-3.x, pywin32, autocad

I am encountering a problem while trying to insert blocks in AutoCAD using the Pywin32 library and pyautocad. I've been working on a project that requires automating some tasks in AutoCAD 2024.

here is my code

`acad = win32com.client.Dispatch("AutoCAD.Application") acadDoc = acad.Documents.Open('dwg file path') blockRefObj = acadDoc.ModelSpace.InsertBlock((0,0,0), 'test_block', 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0)`

trying Pywin32 and PyAutoCAD library

Answer (score 0):

InsertBlock expects a safe array, I think pyautocad has a type APoint
try this:

```
pt = APoint(0.0,0.0,0.0)
acadDoc.ModelSpace.InsertBlock(pt, 'test_block', 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0)
```